# How do I get new textbox value (new one i written) if textbox has Eval value already?

Tags: asp.net, textbox, eval

```
<!-- This is my ascx code -->
<asp:GridView ID="grid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ProductID" OnRowUpdating="grid_RowUpdating">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tb_Name" runat='server' Width="170px" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>                  
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" HeaderText="Confirm" Text="Confirm" CommandName="Update" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

---

```
//My ascx.cs code
protected void grid_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    int rowIndex = e.RowIndex;

    string productID = grid.DataKeys[rowIndex].Value.ToString();
    int productId = Int32.Parse(productID);
    GridViewRow gridRow;

    gridRow = grid.Rows[rowIndex];

    TextBox tname = (TextBox)gridRow.FindControl("tb_Name");


    bool success = CatalogAccess.ProductUpdateItem(productId, tname.Text);

    statusLabel.Text = success ? "Product successfully updated! " + tname.Text.ToString() : "There was an error updating the product";

    PopulateControls();

}
```

My question is, how do i get the new TextBox value that I type in? I cant update, cuz im always getting that Eval value, not the new value that I type in?

Comment: When are you trying to get it?  On submit of form?  Depending on the order of events the Eval is run once the grid is created, then if you have a call on submit or button click that happens after the Eval is run and you can get the updated value then

Comment: Im using this auto generated OnRowUpdating function, so im not sure how it exactly works and when, i thought it was the one ment for updating row values?

Comment: Found my mistake, i didnt have if (!IsPostBack) on Page_Load... 12 hours went for nothing

Comment: Thats usually how it is, one small thing takes forever.  Happens to me all the time, I can write 20 pages of complicated code works fine, I write 5 lines of code and it doesnt work and no clue why!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add  postback method if(!ispostback) in load method and add grid binding method inside it